# How to install NewRelic Mobile in Appcelerator mobile app?

Tags: mobile, appcelerator, newrelic

I am using NewRelic on our web based applications, and since they recently released a mobile version, we would like to incorporate it into our existing Appcelerator app. We commonly use Titanium Studious 3.0.2 for development.

We are using NewRelic iOS Agent 1.309 which essentially is NewRelicAgent.framework package for use in XCode 4.2+.

How do I set it up in the Appcelerator or Titanium Studios, so it would work with our existing application?

We got the framework via : https://marketplace.appcelerator.com/apps/1140?1691569151#overview

The way we usually  do this is we need to copy the framework in `User/Library/Application Support/titanium/ios/module-version/module-code ...`

and add this to the app :

```
<modules>
        <module version="0.1">nameOfYourModule</module>
    </modules>
</ti:app>
```

How do we add this iOS framework to our app in a similar way?

Comment: Sorry but i don't get your problem. You need [this module](https://marketplace.appcelerator.com/apps/5132?1702952854) for your mobile apps. And you can add it vie Help -> Install Titanium Module. Then you can update your tiapp.xml. Where is your problem?

Comment: @mr.VVoo Both the link to the module you provided above, and the link to the module I provided above essentially link to NewRelic website, where they provide iOS package and Android package. Nowhere I can see an actual Titanium module that I could install given the Help -> Install Titanium Module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They didn't actually release it yet.  They more or less created a placeholder for it in the marketplace.

The module itself is being released later in the year from what I understand.